# Undoing a single-file Git Checkout

Tags: xcode, git, commit, rollback, git-checkout

So, I am working on a project with XCode. Happily, I found out that it keeps an Git repository within every project. So, after a mistake on a code, i just used

```
git checkout aux.c
```

to move back from theses mistakes. Unfortunately, as i just found out, Xcode does not auto-commit, so, I ended up with a blank file.
I didn't commited anything  after this, but still can't figure out how to undo this checkout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, undoing a first commit on git is impossible. So, if you are running Xcode, commit manually frequently.

But, there is another way.

If you are running OS X 10.7 Lion or latter (not sure about Snow Leopard), you can try to use the versions feature from OS X to recover any file. Too late for me, but it should work

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you can't. :-(  You're going to have to replace the file some other way.

There are two places where git tracks your files - commits, and the index/staging area. Since there was no commit, and you checked the version of the file out of the staging area, there's no other place it would be.

Do run `git status` just in case, to make sure it doesn't still show staged changes to that file.

Any chance you had it open in an editor still and could undo the changes to the file that `git checkout` made? Some editors like Textmate and SublimeText will allow that; others don't.

Comment: Yeah, I did give a try.... git status shows the file as modified, and XCode immediately reloads the file... Well, working from scratch on this file again...

Comment: Ok, I'm definitely unlucky. Learnt from the hardest way that Xcode does not commit anything automatically. At least I just managed to rebuild almost everything from scratch. Thanks by the help, BTW.
P.S.: Just made a commit. Just to be sure, you know...

Answer (score 1):

If the file has never been committed to the repository then unfortunately you are out of luck.

From the sounds of it, you simply have an empty git repository, which will mean your file has been lost and something Versions (which comes with Lion) or Time Machine may be your best bet at recovering from your mistake.

To confirm if anything has been committed to the repository, use `git log`. If you get an empty response then you're out of luck on the git front.

Unfortunately, this probably this isn't the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Yes, I only get the initial commit, made by Xcode. Well, i trusted way too much on Xcode. Back to scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to recover if your uncommitted changes would be to go to (Left Pane) Source Control Navigator -> Stashed Changes -> Look for a file which dated/timed earlier than your commit which you would like to reverse and click to apply stash changes to the file. That would bring back all the unsaved files back.